How to handle a pole on the real line in a driven linear system with friction
Consider the differential equation
$$
\dot{x}(t) + i \Delta x (t) + (\kappa/2) x(t) = j(t) \, .
$$
We would like to solve for the case
$$j(t) = \cases{1 \quad \text{for } 0 < t < T \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}}
 \, .
$$
Using the Fourier transform
$$\tilde x(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-i \omega t}$$
we have
$$
\tilde x = \frac{\tilde j(\omega)}{i(\omega + \Delta) + \kappa / 2}
$$
and therefore
$$
x(t) = \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \frac{\tilde j (\omega) e^{i \omega t}}{i(\omega + \Delta) + \kappa/2}
\tag{1}
\, .
$$
Our plan is to find $\tilde j$ and then do the integral (1) via contour integration.
The Fourier transform for $j$ is
$$
\tilde j (\omega) = \int_0^T dt \, e^{-i \omega t}
= \frac{e^{-i \omega T} - 1}{-i \omega}
\, .
$$
Plugging that into (1) we get
\begin{align}
x(t)
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}
\frac{e^{-i \omega T} - 1}{-i \omega} \frac{e^{i \omega t}}{i(\omega + \Delta) + \kappa/2} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \frac{e^{i \omega (t - T)} - e^{i \omega t}}{(\omega - 0) (\omega - (-\Delta + i \kappa / 2))} \\
\end{align}
where I've expressed the denominator as a product of poles to facilitate contour integration.
The problem is that there's a pole at $\omega=0$. I don't understand why this has happened because the $\kappa/2$ term introduces "friction" into the system that I would have expected to remove any singularities in the integral... yet there it is. It seems to originate from the form of $j(t)$, yet the function $j(t)$ itself is not pathological as far as I can tell.
Why is this pole at $\omega=0$ there and how should it be handled? I'm guessing that I need to use Sokhotski-Plemelj although it's unclear why there'd be a limit here, and even if that's right I'm still wondering why this funky singularity even exists.
